# Not able to map field in JAXB unmarshalling, fields getting populated as null

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I have an XML that I would like to convert to a POJO using JAXB but I am not able to and all the elements within the parent class are getting populated as `null`.

**Input XML:**

```
<Response>
  <parameters>
    <Id>101</Id>
    <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
  </parameters>
</Response>
```

**FileWriterService.writeMethod()**

```
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
  Response response = (Response) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new 
  StringReader(inputXml));
  System.out.println("response: " + response);
```

**Output:**

```
response: ClassPojo [parameters = ClassPojo [Id = null, Status = null]]
```

**Response.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Response")
public class Response {

    private Parameters parameters;

    public Parameters getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(Parameters parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [parameters = " + parameters + "]";
    }

}
```

**Parameters.java**

```
public class Parameters {

    private String Id;
    private String Status;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String Status) {
        this.Status = Status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [Id = " + Id + ", Status = " + Status + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `@XmlAttribute(name = "Id")  private String id;` and same for status `@XmlAttribute(name = "Status")  private String status;`, because jaxb uses getter setter methods.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but important nonetheless; do not create a new JAXBContext every method call, as it will create a [memory leak](http://javaintherealworld.blogspot.com/2013/10/jaxbcontext-memory-leak.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with @XmlElement annotation, this annotation maps a field to an xml element

Response.java

```
@XmlElement
private Parameters parameters;
```

Parameters.java

```
@XmlElement
private String Id;
@XmlElement
private String Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer Lakshan. After implementing your solution the original problem got resolved but got error related `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions`

In addition to your changes I had to add `XmlAccessorType` as well:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {
```